# Coreplot throws error when downloaded with cocoapods-1.0.1

Tags: ios, swift, cocoapods, core-plot, podfile

I am trying to download coreplot using Cocoapods 1.0.1 and it keeps throwing the error `'CorePlot/CorePlot-CocoaTouch.h' file not found` i tried various solutions given on the web and nothing worked for me. Do help me figure this out.

Here is a sample of my `podfile` code

```
source 'https://github.com/CocoaPods/Specs.git'

platform :ios, '7.0'

xcodeproj 'Sample'

pod 'CorePlot', :git => 'https://github.com/core-plot/core-plot.git', :branch => 'release-2.0'
pod 'Google/Analytics'


target 'SampleKIFTests', :exclusive => true do
  pod 'KIF', '~> 3.3.0'
  pod 'KIF/IdentifierTests', '~> 3.3.0'
end
```

Comment: See [CorePlot issue #304](https://github.com/core-plot/core-plot/issues/304) for more discussion of this question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use this line to include the header when building as a static library:

```
#import "CorePlot-CocoaTouch.h"
```

or this one when building a framework:

```
#import <CorePlot/CorePlot.h>
```

Comment: I tried adding that in Bridging-Header. It didnot work. Is there anything else i should be doing in addition to changing these lines? Tried with `#import <CorePlot/CorePlot.h>` `#import "CorePlot-CocoaTouch.h"` `#import <CorePlot/CorePlot-CocoaTouch.h>`

Comment: I tried downloading the latest version of Coreplot and the same import statements. It still didnot work

Comment: I don't think you are supposed to add anything to the Bridging Header. Try adding it to `YourProject-Swift.h`.

Comment: The bridging header is the right place to include the Core Plot headers with a  Swift project (that's what the Core Plot example apps do). Make sure the header search paths include the Pods folder that holds the Core Plot source.